# Ipad presentModalViewController over an ViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have ViewController(Passwordviewcontroller) which I want to show with "presentModalviewController"

I have an AppDeleage:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Here is My ViewController from which I want the PasswordviewController to show:

```
-ViewDidLoad
{
    self.passwordView = [[PasswordView alloc]initWithNibName:@"PasswordView" bundle:nil];
    [passwordView setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
    [self presentModalViewController:passwordView animated:YES];
}
```

I tried everything but its still not working, has somebody an Idea?

Comment: Is this an exact copy/paste of your code?

Comment: The AppDelegate is the exact code.
But the ViewDidLoad has more to do than only showing the modalViewController.
My ViewController has a View, in that View are WebViews, TableViews and ImageViews.
Do you need more information please ask

Comment: could it be that `ViewDidLoad` should be `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: Hello Irene, ViewDidLoad is working great, only the presentModalViewController is not working...

Comment: If you put it in `-viewDidAppear`, is it working?

Comment: So if I create an Splitview Projekt and tell the DetailViewController [self presentModalViewController:passwordview animated:YES];
Its working like a charm.
But if I create an SingleView Project Its not working!?
Whats wrong?
Maybe that the NavigationController is missing??
I thing its not needed.
I don't need a Splitview!
Plz help, Iam going nuts....

Comment: ViewDidAppear did the trick!
Thank you very much Irene!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in `viewDidAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad`. In `viewDidLoad` your view might be loaded into memory but doesn't have to be on-screen yet. In `viewDidAppear` on the other hand your view is ready to be shown an properly inserted in the window in such a way that you may show modal views.

Edit: Changed `viewWillAppear` to `viewDidAppear` as per comments

Comment: Still don't work, Im going nuts, since 2 Days Iam trying to get that work.

Comment: Just to be sure check if your passwordView gets initialized and is not `nil` and if your `viewWillAppear` really is called.

Comment: Here is my NSLog: <PasswordView: 0x6d55fe0>
PasswordView is initialized correctly did you read my comment, to Irene?

Comment: ViewDidAppear did the trick!
that means the view has to be loaded, afterwards you can present a Modal View....
Thanks for the help.